# Unrecognised Executable taking 100% CPU

Tags: windows, windows-8, virus, cpu-usage, virus-removal

I'm fairly often getting an executable called NMC.exe taking 100% CPU on my Windows 8 (now 10) Laptop.

NMC is the name of my System, I'm not sure if the naming is coincidental or if it is malicious software trying to use the name to seem non threatening, when I do a search of the computer I can't find any NMC.exe and Googling it came up with nothing relevant.

It starts happening at different times whenever I restart (sometimes a few minutes after booting, sometimes hours later). Spybot and Lavasaoft both found nothing, does anyone recognise this pattern of behaviour and have a fix I can try?

Comment: run ProcessExplorer and look for the commandline of the NMC.exe. Maybe this helps you to see what the exe does and where it comes from: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653

Comment: I'll try it next time it appears

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer unexpectedly!

I had another issue caused by the YourTV malware which is well known for changing the omni-box search engine options and preventing you from changing them back, which forced me to download Malwarebytes Anti-Malware, When I ran it, it also unexpectedly found the **NMC.exe** executable in `C:\ProgramData\NMC\NMC.exe` which has been causing me problems. It is a **Bit Coin Miner** which explains the high CPU usage.

[image]

Spybot and Lavasoft both failed to find this (in fact mostly just found tracking cookies, uselessly), so I would recommend the above program. If you don't want to, I've included the screenshot above to show you where to find the offending files.

Answer (score 1):

Following advices:

1. I am sure you googled enough and already checked if it's not [Noritsu NMC](http://processchecker.com/file/NMC.exe.html), but I'm adding this for completeness.
2. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and enter the command "msconfig". Go to the "Services" and/or "Startup" tabs, look for this NMC.exe and untick it or disable it at startup. This should be enough to disable it permanently if it is a legitimate software. When you restart, check if it's active again. In that case it's most probably some kind of malware as it re-enables itself at startup. I would restage the PC at that point.

Comment: Yes I confirmed it wasn't the Noritsu one. Nothing shows up in either services or startup, that's one of the things making me suspicious

Comment: If its not a service and not in the autostart section of msconfig maybe it's in the autostart folder in the start menu? Also, maybe try to rename your PC and see if the program name changes as well on it's own!

Comment: I've found the cause/solution accidentally, thank you for your help though. I've upvoted your answer also just because the steps you suggested are good advice for anyone stumbling here for related issues